# Errors with taking photos and setting it in imageview with Fragments

Tags: android-intent, bitmap, photo, android-camera-intent

I cannot seem to be able to take an photo with the camera and then set it into the imageview. I have tried many different ways but I either receive errors or the image view wont display the photo that I took. I'll post what I have coded at the moment

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_snap, container, false);

    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_display);
    Button camera_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_btn);


    camera_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }

    });

    return view;
}
```

Then for the onActivityResult

```
   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        imageview.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I am now getting this error

```
04-29 19:34:14.946  32713-32713/com.example.tim.cryptpix_10 W/Bundle﹕ Key output expected Parcelable but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value <null> was returned.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public final static int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1034;
public String photoFileName = "photo.jpg";
public final String APP_TAG = "MyCustomApp";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName)); // set the image file name
    // Start the image capture intent to take photo
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         Uri takenPhotoUri = getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName);
         // by this point we have the camera photo on disk
         Log.d("MainActivity photo path",takenPhotoUri.getPath());
         Bitmap takenImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(takenPhotoUri.getPath());
         // Load the taken image into a preview
         ImageView ivPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPreview);
         ivPreview.setImageBitmap(takenImage);   
       } else { // Result was a failure
           Toast.makeText(this, "Picture wasn't taken!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
}

// Returns the Uri for a photo stored on disk given the fileName
public Uri getPhotoFileUri(String fileName) {
    // Get safe storage directory for photos
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), APP_TAG);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists() && !mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "failed to create directory");
    }

    // Return the file target for the photo based on filename
    return Uri.fromFile(new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName));
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for replying! I have implemented your code, I don't get any errors  but my image view still doesnt display anything? I am working in fragments if that is of any help